# In abstract class subclass can access protected data / method of parent class?

Tags: php, oop

```
abstract  class mobile{


    protected function fontcamdef($r){

        return 'it is  '.$r.' MP and type ';
    }
   abstract protected function fontcamflash($ty);
 }

class rep extends mobile{

     function fontcamflash($ty){

        return 'font flash is '.$ty;
    }
}

$obj = new rep();
echo $obj->fontcamdef(6);
echo $obj->fontcamflash('good');
```

When I call `fontcamdef` using object of class `rep`, I am getting an error as below.

> !) Fatal error: Call to protected method
>   mobile::fontcamdef()

Comment: So what did you expect? `protected` allows _the subclass_ to access it, not the outside world. Thats what `public` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call the protected method Out of class

```
abstract  class mobile{
   protected function fontcamdef($r){
      return 'it is  '. $r.' MP and type ';
    }
   abstract protected function fontcamflash($ty);
 }

class rep extends mobile{
        public function fontcamdef1($r)
            {
             return  $this->fontcamdef($r);

            }

     function fontcamflash($ty){
          return 'font flash is '. $ty;
    }
}

$obj = new rep();
echo $obj->fontcamdef1(6);
echo $obj->fontcamflash('good');
```